# How to define struct with an alies in header file in c?

Tags: c

I have the following struct in `node.c`:

```
typedef struct node {
    char something[1024];
    char onething[1024];
    struct node *next;
} LList;
```

How would I define it in `node.h`?

Comment: By moving it to node.h and adding `#include "node.h"`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply move that code to the header file, and include `node.h` in `node.c`.